# Workflow that requests document publishing when a document is modified

Tags: 2010, workflow

Trying to automate publishing requests, so that once a user has modified a document he doesn't have to go through the publish steps.
Since I have a publishing approval workflow I believe I could just create a new workflow that would start this publishing approval workflow for the document that was modified? Can't find a Start Workflow action tho?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just disable the approval workflow mechanism? That way, you don't have to go through all those steps. Only check-in and publish the document. You can even configure SP to publish it immediately.

Comment: Do you mean the publishing approval workflow or the 'Require content approval for submitted items' setting?